# Why there isn't a Functor instance for Kleisli in Control.Arrow?

Tags: haskell, functor, arrows

While trying to familiarize myself with [Control.Arrow](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html), I have noticed that the [Kleisli](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#t:Kleisli) newtype would seem to admit a Functor instance, something like:

```
instance Monad m => Functor (Kleisli m a) where
    fmap f (Kleisli k) = Kleisli $ liftM f . k
```

Is there a reason why this instance isn't provided? Does it exist in some package as an orphan instance?

Comment: My bet is that once you have a -> m b for a monad m, wrapping in Kleisli doesn't add anything new - well, apart from exposing liftM as fmap of a Functor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every arrow can be made into a valid `Functor` by defining

```
fmap f a = a >>> arr f
```

However it's not possible to declare a `Functor` to be a superclass of `Arrow` because of their different kinds (`Functor` needs `* -> *` while `Arrow` needs `* -> * -> *`). So every arrow needs to define the instance separately.

You can wrap any arrow with `ArrowMonad`, which then gives an `Applicative` instance (and therefore also a `Functor`): `instance Arrow a => Applicative (ArrowMonad a) where ...`.

I don't see any particular reason why `Kleisli` lacks the `Functor` instance. The most probable seems to be that you don't need it. If you want to use functorial (or applicative or monadic) operations, you do it on the original monad. You only wrap the monad into `Kleisli` when you need the arrow interface.

Comment: In a pet project of mine, I need to use a Free monad with the Kleisli arrow as the functor, so I can't work in the original monad  directly.

Comment: @DanielDíazCarrete The easiest thing is probably to create an orphan instance yourself: `instance (Monad m) => Functor (Kleisli m a) where fmap = (^<<)`. Or suggest the addition of the `Functor` instance in [Haskell libraries](http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/libraries).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

in `Control.Arrow` is already defined:

```
(>>^) :: Arrow a => a b c -> (c -> d) -> a b d
(^<<) :: Arrow a => (c -> d) -> a b c -> a b d
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you wish to insert `Free` Monad into `Kleisli` - it is impossible, `Free` has one extra parameter `f`.

So you need to use `Arrow Transformer` or create a new `Arrow` class, like

```
class Arrow a => ArrowFunctor f a | a -> f where
    afmap :: a b (f c)
```

Package [arrows](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.1) consist some examples, but it not implement `Free`

Comment: I don't understand how this helps answer the question at all

Comment: @wit As for update#2, I meant something like "type FKleisli o = Free (Kleisli o)"

Comment: @Daniel: sure, you also need to create `newtype FKleisli f m a b = FKleisli { runFKleisli :: a -> m (f b) }` and finally add `instance (Functor f, Monad m, MonadFree f m) => ArrowFunctor (FKleisli f m a) where ...`