# Why isn't Kleisli an instance of Monoid?

Tags: haskell, monads, monoids, kleisli

If you wish to append two functions of type (a -> m b) so you get only one function of the same type appending both results, you could use Kleisli to do so:

```
instance (Monad m, Monoid b) => Monoid (Kleisli m a b) where
    mempty = Kleisli (\_ -> return mempty)
    mappend k1 k2 =
        Kleisli g
            where
                g x = do
                    r1 <- runKleisli k1 x
                    r2 <- runKleisli k2 x
                    return (r1 <> r2)
```

However, currently there is no such instance defined in `Control.Arrow`.
As often, in Haskell, I suspect there is a good reason, but cannot find which one.

#### Note

This question is rather similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925045/why-there-isnt-a-functor-instance-for-kleisli-in-control-arrow). However, with Monoid I don't see a way to define an instance such as:

```
instance (Monad m, Monoid b) => Monoid (a -> m b) where
    [...]
```

since there is already an instance:

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
    [...]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the business of library design, we face a choice point here, and we have chosen to be less than entirely consistent in our collective policy (or lack of it).

`Monoid` instances for `Monad` (or `Applicative`) type constructors can come about in a variety of ways. Pointwise lifting is always available, but we don't define

```
instance (Applicative f, Monoid x) => Monoid (f x) {- not really -} where
  mempty         = pure mempty
  mappend fa fb  = mappend <$> fa <*> fb
```

Note that the `instance Monoid (a -> b)` is just such a pointwise lifting, so the pointwise lifting for `(a -> m b)` does happen whenever the monoid instance for `m b` does pointwise lifting for the monoid on `b`.

We don't do pointwise lifting in general, not only because it would prevent other `Monoid` instances whose carriers happen to be applied types, but also because the structure of the `f` is often considered more significant than that of the `x`. A key case in point is the *free* monoid, better known as `[x]`, which is a `Monoid` by `[]` and `(++)`, rather than by pointwise lifting. The monoidal structure comes from the list wrapping, not from the elements wrapped.

My preferred rule of thumb is indeed to prioritise monoidal structure inherent in the type constructor over either pointwise lifting, or monoidal structure of specific instantiations of a type, like the composition monoid for `a -> a`. These can and do get `newtype` wrappings.

Arguments break out over whether `Monoid (m x)` should coincide with `MonadPlus m` whenever both exist (and similarly with `Alternative`). My sense is that the only good `MonadPlus` instance is a copy of a `Monoid` instance, but others differ. Still, the library is not consistent in this matter, especially not in the matter of (many readers will have seen this old bugbear of mine coming)...

...the monoid instance for `Maybe`, which ignores the fact that we routinely use `Maybe` to model possible failure and instead observes that that the same data type idea of chucking in an extra element can be used to give a semigroup a neutral element if it didn't already have one. The two constructions give rise to isomorphic types, but they are not conceptually cognate. (**Edit** To make matters worse, the idea is implemented awkwardly, giving instance a `Monoid` constraint, when only a `Semigroup` is needed. I'd like to see the `Semigroup`-extends-to-`Monoid` idea implemented, but *not* for `Maybe`.)

Getting back to `Kleisli` in particular, we have three obvious candidate instances:

1. `Monoid (Kleisli m a a)` with `return` and Kleisli composition
2. `MonadPlus m => Monoid (Kleisli m a b)` lifting `mzero` and `mplus` pointwise over `->`
3. `Monoid b => Monoid (Kleisli m a b)` lifting the monoid structure of `b` over `m` then `->`

I expect no choice has been made, just because it's not clear which choice to make. I hesitate to say so, but my vote would be for 2, prioritising the structure coming from `Kleisli m a` over the structure coming from `b`.

Comment: You have "the structure of the f is often considered more significant than that of the f." Is that a mistake?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by your paragraph about `Maybe`. I thought the bugbear of the Maybe monoid was that it *doesn't* have a `Semigroup a => Monoid (Maybe a)` constraint, but rather a `Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a)` constraint, which *ignores* the property that adjoining an element to a semigroup gives a monoid.

Comment: Thanks for the typo spotting. And no, that's not the Maybe bugbear. That's just the insult that's added to the injury.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. And FWIW, it is implemented by `Option` in the `semigroups` package, which is a newtype wrapper around `Maybe`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I just looked. It just gets worse. Concept one: the effect of possible failure and the business of managing it with prioritised choice, which is a notion of computation. Concept two: adjoining a neutral element to a semigroup to get a monoid, which is a notion of value. This repair attempt has not successfully disentagled those concepts.

Comment: Could you give an example of how the former would be represented differently from the latter, given that they are isomorphic? Option sounds like a direct representation of the latter (modulo newtype wrapping) so I'm not quite seeing it.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs You can represent isomorphic types differently by calling them different things (eg, as achieved by newtype). The name is for the idea, for the whole bunch of semantic structures of which the type itself is just the carrier. We get so much effort-saving power by using instance inference to find the right semantic plumbing, keyed to the naming of the concept. It's a shame to muddle the concepts up. When you wonder "how the former would be represented differently" you miss the wood for the trees.

Comment: I don't disagree that naming things is important, or that isomorphic things with different names can have different meanings / represent different ideas. So what then are the "two constructions"? Are they different names with the same implementation? I'd like to understand the distinction you are making a bit more concretely. Can they be written in Haskell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91320/discussion-between-pigworker-and-rein-henrichs).