# What is the idiomatic functional way to apply a list of functions returning an optional successively to a value?

Tags: functional-programming, monads

If i have an entry x and a list of functions x -> Opt[x], what is the idiomatic functional programming way to apply each of the functions successively to get a resulting Opt[x]?

```
x -> [x->Opt[x]] -> Opt[x]
```

Each x -> Opt[x] is some sort of filtering/enriching function, which can either add stuff to x or return nothing if it wants to filter x.

I know the usual suspects like Optional and List monads and their map, apply and bind functions, but i am having a hard time coming up with a solution which feels functional programming idiomatic.

Thank you for any clue into the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545279/126014) is simple and works, so if you're using Haskell or know how to translate `foldM` to your language of choice, that's probably going to be the easiest way to do it.

---

If you're interested in a more generalisable way to think about this problem, however, read on.

I'm going to translate the desired function into Haskell. I'm assuming that

```
x -> [x->Opt[x]] -> Opt[x]
```

is the same as

```
a -> [a -> Maybe a] -> Maybe a
```

in Haskell.

The first thing we might notice is that a pattern starts to emerge if we rearrange the terms a bit:

```
[a -> Maybe a] -> a -> Maybe a
```

Because of currying, that is equivalent to:

```
[a -> Maybe a] -> (a -> Maybe a)
```

The brackets are redundant, so they're only for illustrative purposes. Continuing the didactic line for a moment, suppose we introduce a type alias:

```
type Foo a = a -> Maybe a
```

The above type would now be:

```
[Foo a] -> Foo a
```

So the question is now of a recognisable abstract form of which 'we' know the answer: How do we reduce an arbitrary list of values to a single value?

This is possible if the values in the list give rise to a [monoid](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/10/06/monoids). Specifically in Haskell, this function is [mconcat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mconcat), which generalises to [fold](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold).

This is fun!

The question is, now, does `a -> Maybe a` give rise to a monoid?

That function type is really a Kleisli arrow: `Kleisli Maybe a a`. [Is there a `Monoid` instance for Kleisli arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32935812/126014)? Yes, [at least three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32936292/126014).

We may notice that `Kleisli Maybe a a` looks like an [endomorphism](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/11/13/endomorphism-monoid) because of the repeated `a`. It's not quite an endomorphism, but perhaps we can make it one...

Monadic bind with the arguments flipped (`=<<`) will turn a function `foo` of the type `a -> Maybe a` into an endomorphism:

```
ghci> :t (=<<) foo
(=<<) foo :: Integral b => Maybe b -> Maybe b
```

Almost there. Now wrap it in `Endo` to make it a `Monoid` instance:

```
ghci> :t Endo $ (=<<) foo
Endo $ (=<<) foo :: Integral a => Endo (Maybe a)
```

We're going to need a few functions to play with:

```
projectEven i = if even i then Just i else Nothing
foo i = if i `mod` 10 == 0 then Just (i + 1) else Nothing
```

We can now make a list of these:

```
ghci> :t [foo, projectEven]
[foo, projectEven] :: Integral a => [a -> Maybe a]
```

Map them all to that `Monoid` instance:

```
ghci> :t fmap (Endo . (=<<)) [foo, projectEven]
fmap (Endo . (=<<)) [foo, projectEven]
  :: Integral a => [Endo (Maybe a)]
```

`fold` it:

```
ghci> :t fold $ fmap (Endo . (=<<)) [foo, projectEven]
fold $ fmap (Endo . (=<<)) [foo, projectEven]
  :: Integral a => Endo (Maybe a)
```

and unwrap it:

```
ghci> :t appEndo $ fold $ fmap (Endo . (=<<)) [foo, projectEven]
appEndo $ fold $ fmap (Endo . (=<<)) [foo, projectEven]
  :: Integral a => Maybe a -> Maybe a
```

That's a function from `Maybe a` to `Maybe a`. Since we want `a -> Maybe a`, we can compose it with `Just` so that the 'normal' `a` is lifted to `Maybe a`:

```
ghci> :t (appEndo $ fold $ fmap (Endo . (=<<)) [foo, projectEven]) . Just
(appEndo $ fold $ fmap (Endo . (=<<)) [foo, projectEven]) . Just
  :: Integral a => a -> Maybe a
```

Let's make that a function:

```
runFilters = (appEndo $ fold $ fmap (Endo . (=<<)) [foo, projectEven]) . Just
```

That's just a normal function that you can call:

```
ghci> runFilters 10
Just 11
ghci> runFilters 20
Just 21
ghci> runFilters 2
Nothing
ghci> runFilters 3
Nothing
```

Clearly, this isn't as easy as `foldM`, but may perhaps hint at some deeper abstractions at play.

Really, I just got a bit carried away here, sorry...

Comment: Thank you for the long answer. There is a lot to digest for me as a C++ guy, but i will try to. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell terminology, you're looking for [`foldM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM) where the folding operation calls each of your functions in the list, so `foldM (&)` (= `foldM (\x fn -> fn x)`).

Comment: Thank you, i am currently trying to get my head around that with the help of the haskell docu. :)